# on which basis should i set Input and output shapes in python keras LSTM?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, lstm

I have dataset of shape (143312, 30) and i'm using the following code for setting the model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100,activation='sigmoid', input_shape = (30,1 ) ))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy',f1_m,precision_m, recall_m])
```

It is working but I have no idea why. Is it just about the feature numbers? When I have 30 features then do I simply set it like this? What does 1 mean and on which basis was Dense set to 5?

Answer (score 0):

About this one:

```
LSTM(100,activation='sigmoid', input_shape = (30,1))
```

You have created RNN, which works on sequences of 30 items, each item has one feature. This matches to your data set with shape (143312, 30). The dataset contains 143312 sequences of data, each sequence 30 items long, each item is just a single feature.

The 100 here specifies the number of units (recurrent neurons) used in LSTM. It is a hyperparameter, you use a bigger number for a more complex model and smaller one if your model overfits data.

Regarding this one:

```
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
```

This is an output layer of your model. Apparently you are using your model for classficantion ('softmax' activation function) and your labels have 5 classes, hence 5 neurons in the Dense layer.

Comment: Thank you, but can i ask about 100 what does it mean?

Comment: I have added this now to my answer above.